# MVC-Data not showing on WebGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am very new to MVC and I am trying to retrieve data from Model and displaying on Web Grid but problem is Data is coming in View but not displaying in WebGrid and showing error-
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Helpers.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Column "empId" does not exist.
Here is my code-

//VIEW//

```
@model IEnumerable<EmployeeModel.EmployeeList>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "List";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model);
}



<div id="gridposition" style="width: 100%;">
        @{
            var grid1 = new WebGrid(source: Model, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 10, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridContent");

            @grid1.GetHtml(mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
                tableStyle: "gridTable",
                headerStyle: "gridHead",
                footerStyle: "gridFooter",
                rowStyle: "gridRow",
                alternatingRowStyle: "gridAltRow",
                htmlAttributes: new { id = "positionGrid" },
                fillEmptyRows: false,
                columns: grid1.Columns(
                   grid1.Column("empId", header: "Id"),
                 grid1.Column("empName", header: "Name"),
                 grid1.Column("empAge", header: "Age"),
                 grid1.Column("empDob", header: "Dob"),
                 grid1.Column("addressCountry", header: "Country"),
                 grid1.Column("adsState", header: "State"),
                 grid1.Column("addDistrict", header: "District"),
                 grid1.Column("Qualification", header: "Qualification")))
        }
    </div>
```

//MODEL//

```
public class EmployeeList
   {
       public List<EmployeeDetails> EmpList { get; set; }
       public List<EmailIdDetails> EmailList { get; set; }
       public List<AddressDetail> AddList { get; set; }
       public List<QualificationDetail> QualList { get; set; }
   }
```

Comment: Column "empId" does not exist ! That is something to start :)

Comment: Share your  EmployeeDetails model. May be it is not containing "empId" columns in it

Comment: There is every column and have data. If I remove empId it will give exception next on empName and so on

Comment: public class EmployeeDetails
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Name")]
        [Display(Name = "User Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Age")]
        [Display(Name = "Age")]
        public int Age { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Date of Birth")]
        [Display(Name = "Dob")]
        public string Dob { get; set; }

    }

Comment: I am using entity framework and empId,empName etc all are column of table

Comment: Your model class EmployeeDetails  must contain EmpId property. Thats it

Comment: my model class has Id,Name,Age etc  and when i am writing their name on grid it still shows same error